# The associator is a cocycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products, homotopy-theory

I was trying to get a better intuition about $A_\infty$-algebras, so I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736785/spaces-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-infty-spaces) and tried to fill the details of the answer.

**Context**

More precisely, let $(A, d_A)$ be a differential graded associative algebra and $(B, d_B)$ a deformation retract of $A$, in the sense that there are maps:
$$\begin{align} p &  : A \to B & i : B \to A \end{align}$$
such that $pi = id_B$ and there is a homotopy $h$ acting on $A$ such that $id_A - ip = h d_A + d_A h$.

Then if $\mu : A \otimes A \to A$ is the product on $A$, define a new product $m_2 = m : B \otimes B \to B$ on $B$ by:
$$ m(x,y) = p(\mu(i(x), i(y)))$$

This product is not associative, but I want to prove that

> $$m(m(x,y),z)-m(x,(m(y,z))=d_B m_3(x,y,z) + m_3(d_B x, y, z) + m_3(x,
>  d_B y, z) + m_3(x, y, d_B z)$$

where $m_3 : B \otimes B \otimes B \to B$ is defined by $m_3(u,v,w) = -p \mu(i(u), h\mu(i(v), i(w))) + p \mu(h\mu(i(u), i(v)), i(w))$

**Attempt**

I first computed the associator of the product, because I wanted to gain intuition of why $m_3$ must be defined that way. On the one hand I have

$m(m(x,y),z)=m(p\mu(i(x),i(y)),z)=p\mu (ip(\mu(i(x),i(y))),i(z))$. Since $ip=id_A-hd_A+d_Ah$, using linearity I get

$m(x,m(y,z))=p\mu(\mu(i(x),i(y)),i(z))-p\mu(hd_A(\mu(i(x),i(y))),i(z))-p\mu(d_Ah(\mu(i(x),i(y))),i(z))$

Similarly, I get

$m(x,m(y,z))=p\mu(i(x),\mu(i(y),i(z)))-p\mu(i(x),hd_A(\mu(i(y),i(z))))-p\mu(i(x),d_Ah(\mu(i(y),i(z))))$

Since $\mu$ is associative, the first term of each association cancel, so we get

$$m(m(x,y),z)-m(x,(m(y,z))=$$

$$-p\mu(\mu(i(x),hd_A(\mu(i(y),i(z))))-p\mu(i(x),d_Ah(\mu(i(y),i(z))))+p\mu(hd_A(\mu(i(x),i(y))),i(z))+p\mu(d_Ah(\mu(i(x),i(y))),i(z))$$

After that, I can use that $d_A$ is a derivation, i.e. $d_A\mu=\mu(d_A\otimes 1+1\otimes d_A)$ to make $d_A\circ i=i\circ d_B$ appear in those places where I have $hd_A$.

**Question**

I don't know now how to make $d_B$ appear where I have $d_Ah$. The only way I can think of is replacing this again using the homotopy relation, but I would get some $ip$ that shouldn't appear. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you don't have to move $d_A$ inwards when you have $d_Ah$. Instead, you can move it outwards using $pd_A=d_Bp$. The parts where you move $d_A$ inwards gives you $m_3(d_Bx,y,z)$ and son on, and moving $d_A$ outwards gives you $d_Bm_3(x,y,z)$.